# How to check if log4j2 has been configured or not

Tags: configuration, log4j2

We're all familiar with this message when you don't provide a configuration for log4j2:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

How can I check if log4j2 is not yet configured so that I can initialize with a default configuration if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own ConfigurationFactory and register it with

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFactory
```

That way your ConfigurationFactory will know whether it's been invoked yet or not.

Answer (score 1):

On the first call from your app to log4j2 code, log4j will configure itself before the method returns. If no config file is found, log4j will auto-configure with a default configuration which logs only errors to the console. So from your application's point of view there is never a time that log4j is not configured.

---

One idea is to check if a log4j2.xml file is in the classpath (using Class.getResource), and if it isn't call `System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", pathToYourConfig)`. Note that this *must* be done before the first call to the log4j2 API.

---

An alternative:

Once you have a LoggerContext you can call
`context.setConfigLocation(configLocation)` where configLocation is a URI.
That will force a reconfiguration.

Comment: So how can I accomplish what I want to do, namely initialize with my configuration file when none has been provided?

Comment: I added a suggestion.

Comment: "this must be done before the first call to the log4j2 API." this is too restrictive.

Comment: Once your application starts using log4j2, it configures itself, to ensure it is always in a usable state from your app's point of view. This is by design and unlikely to change. However, you can reconfigure while your app is running. See the config monitor interval configuration attribute.

Comment: I want to be able to write a piece of code that would ensure that log4j2 has been initialized properly with an in house conf (not with the log4j2 default one) though either system property or using Configurator directly.
I believe that's not doable with the log4j2 api.

Comment: The api does not have any initialization logic, no. For that you need to look at the core module. The easy way is to do this at the entry point of your app. Looks like you already found an alternative. Good.

Comment: I also added how one can reconfigure to the answer.