# How to catch errors during log4j2 initialization?

Tags: java, log4j2

We don't consider our app running properly if `log4j2` isn't configured properly as specified in the config file. How do i reliably detect whether errors have occurred during `log4j2` initialization and been printed on the console from java? There are (at least) two sources of bad configuration:

1. The configuration file is entirely missing (or invalid?)
2. The configuration file is valid, but has a problem during `setConfiguration()`.

This question is about the second point. It looks like `log4j2` internally does `try{...} catch(e) { LOGGER.error("bla bla", e) }` during initialization making it impossible to detect such problems.

Errors printed to the console that no human is ever going to see is *bad*. We'd rather have our app crash!

I'm surprised that I can't find a way to programmatically ask `log4j2`: "Did I get the configuration I asked for?". Is there something I have overlooked? E.g. some way to detect whether *anything* has been logged yet?

## Background

Here is the console output we're seeing. Yes, there is permission denied to `/path/to/file` - how do I detect that?

```
2015-10-15 17:43:50,539 main ERROR FileManager (/path/to/file) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/file (Permission denied)
2015-10-15 17:43:50,541 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:794)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:734)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:726)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:383)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:161)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:173)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:422)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:494)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:510)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:199)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:146)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:177)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:447)
        at (our first call to org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger())
```

Looking in the code for `LoggerContext.reconfigure()`, I see:

```
private void reconfigure(final URI configURI) {
    <snip>
    final Configuration instance = ConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(name, configURI, cl);
    setConfiguration(instance);
    <snip>
}
```

And during the call of `setConfiguration()`, there is this in `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build`:

```
    try {
        <snip>
        final Object plugin = factory.invoke(null, params);
        <snip>
        return plugin;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to invoke factory method in class {} for element {}.", this.clazz, this.node.getName(),
            e);
        return null;
    }
```

So the problem was not with `getConfiguration()` from the `ConfigurationFactory`, but with the subsequent `setConfiguration()`, and there seems to be no way to detect that there was a problem... :-(

### About the first point: The configuration file is entirely missing (or invalid?)

We're setting `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=<file>` on the java command line, and there are already [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250527/how-to-detect-missing-log4j2-config) posts on how to detect if `<file>` is missing. [One of which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583836/how-to-check-if-log4j2-has-been-configured-or-not) suggests to `-Dlog4j.configurationFactory` with our own `ConfigurationFactory`.  But no amount of fiddling with our own `ConfigurationFactory` is going to help during `setConfiguration()` to detect the second point ("2." above) as far as I can reason.

We're running log4j2 version 2.4 on openjdk 8 on debian stable/jessie.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the `Log4j2` internals use a special `StatusLogger`, that has a `getStatusData()` method, so here's what to do:

```
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusData;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger;
    ...
    StatusLogger statusLogger = StatusLogger.getLogger();
    if (statusLogger.getStatusData().size() > 0) {
        System.out.printf(
                "Logged %d messages\n",
                statusLogger.getStatusData().size()
            );
        // Investigate List<StatusData> if you want
        for(StatusData data : statusLogger.getStatusData()) {
            System.out.printf(
                    "    Level %s message: %s\n",
                    data.getLevel(),
                    data.getMessage().getFormattedMessage()
                );
        }
        System.err.println("exiting due to unexpected console status logs");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: where i will use this code, in my case I am first checking that if log4j.xml is present then use that XML configuration. For that I am using 
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "abc.log4j.xml"); and then initializing my logger object like
logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyApplication.class); while if file is not present then i am creating the configuration by my own and using 
Configurator.initialize(builder.build()); for initializing. 
I am facing the same problem as yours but don't know where to use the code which you suggested.

Comment: Nowhere log4j2 throws me an exception so that I can catch it and stop my application. Also in my case I don't want this permission denied stacktrace to print on my console I just want message to print on the console but I am not getting how to get that control as it is internally printed by log4j2.